# How to Compare two files line by line and output the whole line if different

Tags: bash, shell, awk, text-processing

I have two sorted files in question

```
1)one is a control file(ctrl.txt) which is external process generated
2)and other is line count file(count.txt) that I generate using `wc -l`
```

$more ctrl.txt

```
Thunderbird|1000
Mustang|2000
Hurricane|3000
```

$more count.txt

```
Thunder_bird|1000
MUSTANG|2000
Hurricane|3001
```

I want to compare these two files ignoring wrinkles in column1(filenames) such as **"_"** (for Thunder_bird) or **"upper case"** (for MUSTANG) so that my output only shows below file as the only real different file for which counts dont match.

```
Hurricane|3000
```

**I have this idea to only compare second column from both the files and output whole line if they are different**

I have seen other examples in AWK but I could not get anything to work.

Comment: Please always try to add your efforts too in your post as we all are here to learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try following `awk` and let me know if this helps you.

```
awk -F"|" 'FNR==NR{gsub(/_/,"");a[tolower($1)]=$2;next} {gsub(/_/,"")} ((tolower($1) in a) && $2!=a[tolower($1)])' cntrl.txt count.txt
```

Adding a non-one liner form of solution too now.

```
awk -F"|" '
FNR==NR{
  gsub(/_/,"");
  a[tolower($1)]=$2;
  next}
{ gsub(/_/,"") }
((tolower($1) in a) && $2!=a[tolower($1)])
' cntrl.txt count.txt
```

***Explanation:*** Adding explanation too here for above code.

```
awk -F"|" '                                ##Setting field seprator as |(pipe) here for all lines in Input_file(s).
FNR==NR{                                   ##Checking condition FNR==NR which will be TRUE when first Input_file(cntrl.txt) in this case is being read. Following instructions will be executed once this condition is TRUE.
  gsub(/_/,"");                            ##Using gsub utility of awk to globally subtitute _ with NULL in current line.
  a[tolower($1)]=$2;                       ##Creating an array named a whose index is first field in LOWER CASE to avoid confusions and value is $2 of current line.
  next}                                    ##next is awk out of the box keyword which will skip all further instructions now.(to make sure they are read when 2nd Input-file named count.txt is being read).
{ gsub(/_/,"") }                           ##Statements from here will be executed when 2nd Input_file is being read, using gsub to remove _ all occurrences from line.
((tolower($1) in a) && $2!=a[tolower($1)]) ##Checking condition here if lower form of $1 is present in array a and value of current line $2 is NOT equal to array a value. If this condition is TRUE then print the current line, since I have NOT given any action so by default printing of current line will happen from count.txt file.
' cntrl.txt count.txt                      ##Mentioning the Input_file names here which we have to pass to awk.
```

Comment: This works.Can you explain this code so that I can start tweaking it  on my own for further changes

Comment: @cheapcoder, sure will add explanation too in sometime.

Comment: @ RavinderSingh13 : Can you also help with awk  code for **"only compare second column from both the files and output whole line if they are different"** because I am having more situations where I have to gsub

Comment: @cheapcoder, I would request you to open a new thread with all details as it could confuse users who are reading this thread to get some more knowledge. Also please do mention all details like do 1st field could be duplicated or so, please do mention all details, cheers and keep learning.